# How to get changable value into one textbox ng-repeat using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

repeat in `angularjs` i have two **textbox** in repeat when i change **textbox1** values means i need automatically **textbox** 2 will get the 0 based row (index) value help how to do this

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">

                    <input type="text" ng-model="product.name"   />
                    <input type="text" ng-model=""  />  
</div>
```

Comment: use the same model for second text input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Please go with `$index`// object

```html
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script> 
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <input type="text" ng-change="changeVal(product,$index)" ng-model="product.name"   />
        <input type="number" ng-value="values" ng-model="product.name2"   />  
    </div>
</div>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.values=0;
    $scope.products=[{name:''},{name:''}];
    $scope.changeVal=function(product,index)
    {
        product.name2=1;       
    }
}]);
</script>
```

Comment: sry bro when i change first textbox current relavant textbox2 value change into 0 how
if i change first row textbox that relavant textbox2 value should be change into 0

Comment: my need is when textbox value change means i need to show 0 in textbox 2 using ng-change and row index@Ramesh help

Comment: OOPS! please checkout the snippet.

Comment: i am no need to show the index value into textbox 2 i have some value bind textbox1 that value having some changes means that means  user can edit the value of textbox1 means i show 1 into textbox 2 may be no changes in textbox1 means i need to show 0 in textbox2

Comment: not clear. You want to show the number of count whenever the textbox1 change event fire?

Comment: no ramesh i want show only two values in textbox2 0 and 1 how means whenever data change in textbox 1 means then i show textbox 2 value is 1 otherwise 0

Comment: I have update my answer. let me know this is what you want or not

Comment: no need to add with index when textbox value change means want show 1 otherwise 0

Answer (score 1):

I have changed @Ramesh's code. Whenever a model value changes, you change its changeStatus to 1.

```html
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script> 
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <input type="text" ng-change="changeVal($index)" ng-model="product.name"   />
        <input type="number" ng-model="product.changeStatus"/>  
    </div>
</div>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.values=0;
    $scope.products=[{name:'p1', changeStatus: 0},{name:'p2', changeStatus: 0}];
    $scope.changeVal=function(index) {
        $scope.products[index].changeStatus = 1;
   }
 }]);
</script>
```